# Buscador en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Hola amigos como estan trato de hacer un buscador por id y por nombre pero no se como  hacerlo solamente se hacerlo que busque por un solo requisito pero necesito que busque por dos o mas tengo algo asi

```
$texto = $request->input('texto');
    $productos = Producto::query()
    ->where('id', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(1);
    return view('productos.index', compact('productos'));
```

Trate de hacer algo asi

```
    $texto = $request->input('texto');
    $productos = Producto::query()
    ->where('id', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(1);
    return view('productos.index', compact('productos'));
```

Pero no me funciono

Por favor si me pueden ayudar a solucionar esto les agradeceria

Comment: Si asi es amigo si esto no debe ser asi por favor me dices

Comment: Mi buscador funciona bien si le le pongo un solo requisito pero necesito que sean dos o mas por ejemplo para buscar por ID nombre o descripcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que quieres hallar los registros que tengan coincidencias en cualquiera de los dos campos, puedes utilizar el método `orWhere` para agregar una condición unida por un operador lógico `or`.  Actualmente, al utilizar `where` son unidos por `and` y por eso no encuentra coincidencias, pues solo traería los registros que tengan coincidencia en ambos campos.

La [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#or-where-clauses) dice:

> When chaining together calls to the query builder's `where` method, the "`where`" clauses will be joined together using the `and` operator. However, you may use the `orWhere` method to join a clause to the query using the `or` operator. The `orWhere` method accepts the same arguments as the where method.

Mi traducción libre:

> Al encadenar llamadas al método `where` del generador de consultas, las cláusulas "`where`" se unirán mediante el operador `and`. Sin embargo, puede usar el método `orWhere` para unir una cláusula a la consulta usando el operador `or`. El método `orWhere` acepta los mismos argumentos que el método where.

En código luciría algo como:

```
 $texto = $request->input('texto');
    $productos = Producto::query()
    ->where('id', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->orWhere('nombre', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(1);
    return view('productos.index', compact('productos'));
```